# Proof that $n^n<(n!)^2$ for $n>2$

Tags: inequality, induction

> Prove that $n^n<(n!)^2$ for $n>2$

I tried math induction, but couldn't prove that $(k+1)^{k+1}<((k+1)!)^2$.

Comment: Just a moment, I've proved it by induction, I think indeed it is quite fun.

Comment: See an identical question at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/801526/131263 (I gave a non-inductive answer to it: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/801566/131263).

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answers, consider accepting one. Thanks for the question, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to 
$$
\underbrace{n\cdot n \cdot\cdots\cdot n}_{n} \leq 1^2\cdot 2^2\cdot \cdots\cdot n^2=(1\cdot n)(2\cdot (n-1))\cdots (n\cdot 1)
$$

Hence it remains to show that $n \le k(n+1-k)$ for $n\ge k \ge 1$.

$n \le k(n+1-k) \iff n \le kn+k-k^2 \iff  (k-k^2)+(kn-n) \ge 0 \iff (k-n)(1-k) \ge 0$.

but $(k-n)(1-k) \ge 0$ iff $(k-n)(k-1) \le 0$, and this happens iff $k$ is between $1$ and $n$ inclusive. 
Hence we have proved our claim and solved the problem

Comment: Thank for Your answer. I understood Your prooving.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the inductive step:$$(n+1)^{n+1}<((n+1)!)^2 \\ (n+1)^{n+1}<n!\cdot n!\cdot(n+1)^2 \\ (n+1)^{n-1}<n!\cdot n!.  $$ Hence it suffices to show $$(n+1)^{n-1}\le n^n,$$ and indeed it is equivalent to $$(n+1)^n\le n^n(n+1) \\ \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\le n+1.$$
Since the LHS is bounded by $e$, the latter inequality holds for all $n\ge2,$ and by calculation we have equality for $n=1$. And thus we're done.

**Edit** suggested by @user161825:

In fact, for $n\ge 2$ we have that $\displaystyle \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$ strictly decreases, hence we obtain $$\frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}\le \frac{3}{4} $$ for $n> 2$.

Comment: Note that your computation shows that $n^n/(n!)^2$ is a decreasing sequence for all $n≥1$. In particular, you obtain the sharp bound $n^n/(n!)2\leq 3/4$ for $n≥3$

Comment: @user161825 Are you suggesting adding this with an edit? I was more interested in proving the OP's inequality, but I might well add it.

Comment: It was only meant as a side remark, whether you wish to add it is up to you. I found it interesting in relation to my own somewhat worse estimate below.

Comment: @user161825 Yes, I see. I'll add it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To do this you first prove: $(k+1)^k < k^{k+1}$ by induction.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an argument based on [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$
\frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}\leq \frac{e^n}{n!\sqrt{2\pi n}}\leq \frac{e^3}{6\sqrt{6\pi}}< 0.78.
$$
This follows from the observation that the sequence $\left(\frac{e^n}{n!\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)_{n\geq 3}$ is decreasing since $n\geq e$ in this range.